# Why doesn't Xcode create a .gitignore file?

Tags: xcode, git

I'm aware of how to create one and there are lots of posts of what should be in them for an Xcode project. This is a more basic question.

- When creating a new Xcode project with the git option why doesn't Xcode create a default .gitignore file?

Assume that I'm just working locally, I haven't created any remotes.

- If I don't add a .gitignore myself does that mean that the files that are usually added to a .gitignore (like .DS_Store and *.xcuserdatad for example) are being managed by git? Is this bad?
- Or is Xcode doing something behind the scenes to ignore those files?

Comment: You can search for a base `.gitignore` in https://github.com/github/gitignore. For example, [Objective-C.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Objective-C.gitignore)

Comment: @pktangyue Thanks. I've edited my question to be more clear that I'm not asking where to get one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that Xcode does not create a gitignore file on its own. So this is how I start a new project now.

1. Create a new project in Xcode. Do not create a local git repo. The problem with getting Xcode to create the repo is that it performs an initial commit before a gitignore file is created. I prefer to add gitignore before the initial commit.
2. Close the project.
3. In Terminal, navigate to the directory containing the
   new project.
4. `git init`
5. `curl https://www.gitignore.io/api/xcode > .gitignore` There are lots of places to get gitignore files but this is super handy as shown on NSScreencast episode 156.
6. `git add .`  Be sure to include the dot, that adds everything.
7. `git commit -m “Initial commit."`
8. Open the project in Xcode and inspect the `Source Control` menu. If you select `History` you should see the initial commit.

Update:

`www.gitignore.io` now redirects to `www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore`

It's nice. You can specify keywords like xcode, cocoapods, etc.

Comment: Starting in Xcode 10:  Xcode -> Preferences -> Source Control -> Git you can now specify a `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Yes, now in Xcode (12.4) you can specify files to ignore, but the UI is terrible. You can add only one file at a time, so you can't copy-paste from another .gitignore. And it's hard to read. Not sure if it even handles comments.